# Omniauth.rb Fitbit expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth, fitbit

I'm trying to set up omniauth with the [fitbit](/questions/tagged/fitbit) api.

I created a file in **config/initializers/omniauth.rb**:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :fitbit, b4aaad9b1 , 88bd74511f
    #NOT THE ACTUAL KEYS - I deleted middle numbers to preserve formatting
end
```

when I run:

```
rails s
```

I receive the error

```
gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': config/initializers/omniauth.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Any ideas how to fit this. I am very new to [oauth-2.0](/questions/tagged/oauth-2.0) and [omniauth](/questions/tagged/omniauth):

thanks

Comment: just check you have commas in the right places in the actual file - is this the entire contents of the initializer file?

Comment: Shouldn't you enclose your keys in '' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way to pass a [string](/questions/tagged/string) into a method, or even to use it at all, is to close it to single or double quotes. See it on your example:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :fitbit, 'b4aaad9b1', '88bd74511f'
end
```